# Trying to redirect to default if file containing 'index_'+storeNum+'html?s'+storeNum; doesn't exist

Tags: jquery

I have code to look for a file containing `'index_'+storeNum='.html?s='+storeNum`.

I would like to find a way to say if that does not exist to default to `default.html`. I still seem to get a 404 with the code I am using

```js
var url = getParameterByName('url');
var storeNum = getParameterByName('s');
var promo = getParameterByName('promo');

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.container').css({
    height: wh
  });

  if (storeNum) {
    url = 'index_' + storeNum + '.html?s=' + storeNum;
  } else {
    url = 'default.html';
  }

  $('#content').attr('src', url);
});
```

I have tested this. It never goes to the else statement as it always "finds" a page, but it is a non existent page resulting in the 404. This is how I pass in the store index.html?s=6008. I then have a list of index files, index_6008.html, index_6009.html, etc. Not sure why it wouldn't hit the else if the file doesn't exist. The issue I am having is that it always will hold a value as we always pass in a number in the URL.

Comment: Your logic looks ok. The only logical conclusion is that `storeNum` does not hold the value you expect. Have you tried debugging this at all? We can't really help without seeing the context you're working in

Comment: Welcome to SO Kevin, `getParameterByName` is not a standard method of JS as far as I am aware? Can you please post the code for this function?

Comment: @Panomosh - This Is the getParameterByName code:
    var url = getParameterByName('url');
    //var storeNum = getParameterByName('s');
    var promo = getParameterByName('promo');

     function getParameterByName( name )
    {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec( window.parent.location.href );
    if( results == null )
    return "";
    else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }